# Headless chrome: chrome not reachable

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, protractor, google-chrome-headless

I am using Chrome headless to run the protractor test. It runs for a while but after that i get the following error.

> [15:36:30] E/launcher - chrome not reachable   (Session info:
>   headless chrome=59.0.3071.115)   (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.30.477690
>   (c53f4ad87510ee97b5c3425a14c0e79780cdf262),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.6
>   x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace
>   information) Command duration or timeout: 5 milliseconds Build info:
>   version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'

The configuration is as shown below.

```
 capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
      'args': ['headless', 'disable-gpu']
    }
```

Tests run fine when i run without the 'headless' args.

Answer (score -1):

Update capabilities as it shows in the official manual:

```
capabilities: {
  browserName: 'chrome',

  chromeOptions: {
     args: [ "--headless", "--disable-gpu"]
   }
}
```

You could take a look at [Using headless Chrome](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/browser-setup.md) section